# Is it possible to make a ListView populate from the bottom?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a simple application which basically consists of a line of buttons and a ListView of items to be selected and manipulated.  There might be only one item in the list or a few.  However, I would prefer if the list would populate from the bottom of the ListView, since the way most people hold their phones makes it easier to select items closer to the bottom of the screen.  Is this possible?

Comment: what exactly you want. if im not wrong suppose you have three items 1,2,3 then your list with must comtain 3,2,1 thats it or not

Comment: You wanna display your content from bottom in listivew, is it?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can have the `ListView` stack its items from the bottom up using a simple XML property
under the xml -

```
<ListView 
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
...
></ListView>
```

Please read @The Berga answer to otherwise this won't work.

Comment: i want to show list from top to bottom, and you answer helped me alot i get the idea from where i can changed it..  Thnks man...

Answer (score 19):

Joe answer is correct but it's important to point out that it only works if the `ListView`'s width and height are set to `match_parent` or `fill_parent`.

If set to `wrap_content` it still will populate from top to bottom.

Comment: Upvoted. Good one. Better to edit @Joe answer by yours

Answer (score 0):

I tried `android:stackFromBottom="true"` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"` but it didn't work

finally

```
  Adapter.insert(post,0);
```

saved my day. Here post is the class which is returning data to be added

Answer (score 0):

These are **a must tags** for the reverse populating of the list view.

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
</ListView>
```