# ListView populates from the bottom instead of from the top

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a listView that expands upwards instead of downwards.
I have another listView on another page that works just fine and populates itself from the top -> bot.
Why does my listView start from the bottom instead of the top?

My XML
`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_showRegister"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/showRegister"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:clickable="false" >

</ListView>`
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Also, try to add more tags like "android" ;-) Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Just noticed that I didnt ask any question, Im just wondering why my listView is populating itself from the bottom and up. I want it to expand downwards. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look a these links. [Is it possible to make a ListView populate from the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987402/is-it-possible-to-make-a-listview-populate-from-the-bottom). populating from bottom.
[Add new items to top of list view on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903597/add-new-items-to-top-of-list-view-on-android). Add new  item at the top of list.

Answer (score 27):

Your `ListView` is still actually populating from the top downwards. Just not from the top of the page.

You have set the `layout_height="wrap_content"` and the `layout_above="@+id/showRegister"`. With the height being `wrap_content`, the view *will only be as large as it's contents*. Then, due to the fact you have used `layout_above`, it will be *directly above another view*.

The listview is not filling from the bottom, it is filling from the top (of the listview) - but the listview itself is only starting from halfway up the screen. Anything above the listview is *not actually part of the listview*, but empty space instead.

**The solution is to either set the `layout_height="match_parent"`, or remove the `layout_above` tag.**

I know this is an old question but I hope this helps anyone else who may have found this issue via google.

Comment: u r the champ...! Thank you Teifi

Answer (score 9):

See for [android:stackFromBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3astackFromBottom) attribute.