# How to make a list view populate from the bottom up

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, bottom-up

right now i have a list view that populates like

```
[top]
1
2
3
4
[bottom]
```

I want it to populate like

```
[top]
4
3
2
1
[bottom]
```

. `android:stackFromBottom="true"` is not giving me what i want

Answer (score 1):

override `getItem` and instead of returning the data set entry at `position`, return the entry at `dataset.size() - position - 1`. E.g

Assuming the dataset is composed of `String`s, and you are storing those in an `ArrayList<String>()` called `mDataSet`

```
 @Override
 public String getItem(int position) {
    return mDataSet.get(dataset.size() - position - 1);
 }
```

Comment: So lets say i have an array of "Tips".   Will I?

Comment: Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mTips.length - position - 1;
    }   @Blackbelt

Comment: almost: `mTips[mTips.length - position - 1]`

Comment: im overiding that in my custom adapter but its not working :(  @Blackbelt

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this:
[Is it possible to make a ListView populate from the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987402/is-it-possible-to-make-a-listview-populate-from-the-bottom)

> It only works if the ListView's width and height are set to
>   match_parent or fill_parent.