# Android RecyclerView (or ListView) design like Lollipop Notifications

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-5.0-lollipop

I would like to make a similar design to my `RecyclerView` (or if it's not possible maybe a `ListView` can do that) like the one in the status bar (or Lock Screen) of Android Lollipop and up.

I am mainly interested in how they stack on top of each other when they no longer fit into the screen. And the way they slide up is they go each one behind the one above it.

Here are some images (they are stacked in the second screen): [one](http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/blog/en/2014/10/22-android-5.0-lollipop-notifications-568x506.png), [two](http://techreport.com/r.x/2014_11_17_A_first_taste_of_Lollipop_on_Nvidias_Shield_Tablet/notifications.jpg).

I know how to use the `RecyclerView` with default scrolling behaviour and such but the one described above is very interesting. How is it possible?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987402/is-it-possible-to-make-a-listview-populate-from-the-bottom)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I basically need that stacking effect (one over each other).