# How to fetch data from Firebase in Android listView on time precedence?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm making a social media app, I am sending user's posts to firebase and then I'm retrieving them in Android listView, but I am getting the newer posts at the bottom. I want my app to work just like Facebook i.e to fetch data and set them on listView according to the precedence of time (newer posts on top).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987402/is-it-possible-to-make-a-listview-populate-from-the-bottom

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need to add for each post in you database, a new field containing a `TIMESTAMP` and then order the posts accordingly to this. To set the TIMESTAMP i recomand you using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` and for getting the data back the following method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey is there any way i can retrieve all the posts posted in current date?

Comment: Yes, using the solution above. Having the `TIMESTAMP` you can query your database according to it, as you want. You can use methods like startAt(), endAt(), limitToFirst() or limitToLast().